# No more routes available after Twig's render() function

Tags: symfony, twig

I’m facing a weird behavior from Symfony 2.5.5 (PHP 5.6.1), more specifically Twig. Here is a fragment of my template layout:

```
<nav>
    {% render controller('SGLotteryGameBundle:Home:lastDraw') %}
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li><a href="{{ path('sg_lottery_home') }}">{{ 'SuperWinner'|trans }}</a></li>
        {% block bc %}{% endblock %}
    </ol>
</nav>
```

This template worked fine until I added the `render` call. After that, Symfony reported:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "sg_lottery_home" as such route does not exist.")
in /home/kevin/Prog/PHP/SG2/src/SG/Lottery/GameBundle/Resources/views/layout.html.twig at line 70.
```

Of course, the `sg_lottery_home` is defined and works well without the `render` block. If I comment the path generation of this route, the immediate next one fails. Routes before the tag are rendered without any issue.

Here is the `SGLotteryGameBundle:Home` controller:

```
<?php
namespace SG\Lottery\GameBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Template
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return [];
    }

    public function lastDrawAction()
    {
        return new Response('Dummy');
    }
}
```

I tried replacing `{% render ... %}` by `{{ render(...) }}`, without any change.

**Important note:** it only happens when I’m logged in.

Comment: This is really weird. Can't seem to spot the issue here and I'm really interested what could have gone wrong. Did you consider downgrading to `2.5.0` in order to confirm the bug?

Comment: also, by all means, use the `{{ render(...) }}` call instead of `{% render %}` as the later one is deprecated...

Comment: Note that if I clear the cache, I get the exact same error but on line 61 where there is only `<div class="panel-heading">{{ 'Next Euro Millions draw'|trans }}</div>`; if I refresh, it shows line 70.

Comment: @jperovic Downgrading to 2.5.0 didn't change this behavior, excepted it reports the error on line 48 (`<li><a href="">{{ 'Draws'|trans }}</a></li>`) right after clearing cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, it was caused by `JMSI18nRoutingBundle` generating an error while retrieving the user's locale: the available locales were `en` and `fr` and the user's locale `fr_FR`. I have no idea how the `{{ render(...) }}` call interacted with that.